# laravel orm adds 's' with table name

Tags: php, laravel

```
    $user = new User();
    $user->name=$request['name'];
    $user->email=$request['email'];
    $user->password=$request['password'];
    $user->save();
```

> /* SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Avijit Acharjee, avijitach@gmail.com, 12345, 2019-11-20 19:33:12, 2019-11-20 19:33:12) */

The above code converts into the commented sql. It adds 's' to the table name. How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

This is the default Laravel behaviour.

Unless specified, the `table` it looks for when querying the model is the lowercase plural version of the Class name. So, in this case, `User` converts to `users` when querying.

To handle this, set the `table` on the Model:

```php
class User extends Model {
   protected $table = "user";

   ...
}
```

Note: This goes against standard naming conventions, but the option is available if you need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot . It worked nicely .